# How to store data in Bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Here are the steps that I want to be able to do in Bixby:
1. User says an utterance.
2. The Capsule then makes an API Call.
3. Store the returned data from the API Call locally.
4. User says a different utterance.
5. The API Call will send a piece of the stored data to the Endpoint.

I want to be able to store data so I can reuse it for future utterances. How can I do this?

I can only find this to be possible if the utterances are sequential by calling the functions consecutively however in my use case it is possible to be not sequential and I want to be able to re-use those values in other Bixby sessions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to store this state via an external API call as the state is not maintained after exiting the capsule or across the request.  See "[Capsule and Context State](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions)", but here is the relevant info ...

> Context between capsules is not stateful, meaning that if the user
>   leaves the capsule for another capsule or if the user leaves Bixby
>   altogether, then any context for the first capsule is not guaranteed
>   to be remembered.
>
> If your capsule does need to remember context between various states,
>   you should use the content provider. You can store as much information
>   on the content provider side as needed. You can always use remote
>   endpoints and set up your service how you want.